# How can I do a data type validation on a field that is dependent on another field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-attribute-value

I am having trouble performing **data type validation** which is dependent on another field. Most of the examples I found here are for making a field required or not based on a value of another field (`MaidenName` will be required only if `IsMarried` is `true`).

My Model

```
public class AttributeValuesModel
{
    public IList<AttributeModel> Values {get; set;}
}

public class AttributeModel
{
    [Required]
    public string AttributeName {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string AttributeValue {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public int DataTypeId {get; set;}
}
```

What I would like to do is to validate the user input for AttributeValue based on the value of DataTypeId. For clarity, the value of `DataTypeId` is known before I even show the view to the user.

```
    //Possible values for DataTypeId are 
    //1 for decimal
    //2 for dates
    //3 for integer
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so hard to roll your own validation attribute. I have implemented one some time ago. It checks whether value of other property is smaller than property that is decorated with this attribiute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited=true)]
public class SmallerThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public SmallerThanAttribute(string otherPropertyName)
    {
        this.OtherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
    }

    public string OtherPropertyName { get; set; }
    public string OtherPropertyDisplayName { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return IsValid(OtherPropertyName, value, validationContext);
    }

    private ValidationResult IsValid(string otherProperty, object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        PropertyInfo otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(otherProperty);

        if (otherPropertyInfo == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not find property: " + otherProperty);
        }

        var displayAttribute = otherPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;

        if (displayAttribute != null && OtherPropertyDisplayName == null)
        {
            OtherPropertyDisplayName = displayAttribute.GetName();
        }

        object otherPropertyValue = otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        var smaller = (IComparable) value;
        var bigger = (IComparable) otherPropertyValue;

        if (smaller == null || bigger == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (smaller.CompareTo(bigger) > 0)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format(ValidatorResource.SmallerThan, validationContext.DisplayName, OtherPropertyDisplayName));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

There is one gotcha. Error message format is defined in resource class property (ValidatorResource.SmallerThan), so it's not pluggable -- I didn't need this. However, I think it still could be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [`FoolProof`](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) validation extensions for ASP.NET MVC. They contain validation attributes which could be used to perform conditional validation such as `[RequiredIf]`.

And an even more powerful validation library (and the one that I use and recommend) is [`FluentMVC`](http://fluentmvc.codeplex.com/). Contrary to validation data annotations this library allows you to perform imperative validation instead of declarative. This allows you to express rules of arbitrary complexity and between dependent properties.

Comment: I've seen FoolProof before posting my question but I think they don't do data type validations. The closest that they have is `[RequiredIfRegExMatch]` and `[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]` which I feel is a bit pushing it to the limit to do data type validations. I'll check FluentMVC as it has a mention of `DataType` in the Model Template section (bottom of the page).

Comment: Well then with FluentMVC you get all the joy (and power).

Comment: Since you said that you've used `FluentMVC`, I was wondering if you've used the built-in `DataType` template in a similar situation as I am in now? Meaning that the data type validation fires only when the dependency to another field has been met.

Comment: I tried FluentMVC and this is what I got working: `context.RulesFor(x=> x.AttributeValue).Required(c => c.Message("not valid").StopOnFail());` but this one doesn't `context.RulesFor(model => model.AttributeValue).Required(c => c.Message("not valid").When(x => x.DataTypeId == 1).StopOnFail());` Somehow, DataTypeId is always `0`. What did I miss? :)

Comment: You probably missed to POST the value of this property to the controller action when you submitted the form. Or if you have a corresponding field in the form you didn't respect the correct naming convention that the model binder expects.